# Creating a function which limits user string input to a maximum of 30 characters with no spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, input

This is my first post here so apologies if formatting is incorrect

I am a newcomer to coding having started Python recently in college and I am currently working on a project. Part of this project is to prompt the user for a string input, only allowing max. 30 characters and no spaces i.e. one word , then re-prompting the user for said input if the requirements are not met. I would like to assign this operation to a function which I have thus far failed to achieve. I am sure this is a relatively simple fix but as mentioned I am a newbie to the world of coding so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the function, we use a while loop to keep prompting the user until they provide a valid input.

```
def get_valid_input():
    while True:
        user_input = input("Enter a single word with a maximum of 30 characters (no spaces): ")

        if user_input.isalpha() and len(user_input) <= 30:
            return user_input  # Return the input if it's valid (While will be promoting the user until the input is valid)
        else:
            print("Invalid input. Please try again.")

user_word = get_valid_input()
print(f"You entered: {user_word}")
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks a lot